# AVPlayer too big for screen

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to play a video in a scrollView. For that matter, I ended up using an AVPlayerViewController because it worked really well with the spacing between multiple videos. The problem is however, that all the videos are approx. 1/3 bigger than the size of the screen. What did I do wrong?

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: videoLink))
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect            
playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height) * CGFloat(index), UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,0)
```

**UPDATE:**

The following code still shows the video. The frame is really small, but still shows. I tried debugging it by printing out its "view.frame.bounds.width", "view.frame.bounds.size.width", "view.frame.size.width", and "view.frame.width" and they all said "0"

```
playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 64) * CGFloat(index) + 30, 0, 0)
```